# How many threads are supported by JMeter for (1 Core 2GB RAM)?

Tags: jmeter

I am currently using JMeter command line to trigger load test under master(2GB Memory & 1 Core) and slave machine(2GB Memory & 1 Core)

How many threads are supported by JMeter for above configuration.

Do we need to change any thing in Heapsize to get maximum threads?

Can any one help in this regard.

Comment: See this if you want to scale as never before:https://medium.com/@nirmalmewada/unveiling-the-secret-achieving-50k-concurrent-user-load-using-jmeter-with-2-5g-ram-only-51f892b233ce

Answer (score 0):

We don't know, it might be the case even 1 thread is not supported, it might be the case [2147483647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647) users are supported.

The number of virtual users you can simulate varies and depends on different factors like:

1. The nature of the test (what protocols are in scope, what exactly the test is doing, etc.) For simple GET request with small response you will be able to simulate more users, for complex POST request with a lot of calculated encrypted parameters uploading several large files the number of users will be much less
2. The size of request and response
3. The number of [pre](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors)/[post processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), etc.

So the only way of telling how many users you can simulate to measure it

1. Make sure to have monitoring of essential OS health metrics like CPU, RAM, etc. usage is in place. If you don't have any solutions in mind you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
2. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
3. Start with 1 user and gradually increase the load at the same time looking at the CPU, RAM, Network, disk usage, etc.
4. When any of monitored metrics starts exceeding, say, 80% of maximum available capacity take a look at how many threads are online just before this moment using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener
5. This is how many users you can simulate **for particular this test on particular this hardware/software combination**